# AJAX receives 500 Internal server error when calling ASP.NET MVC Controller

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'am receiving a 500 internal server error when trying to call a controller action using Javascript AJAX.

I want to call a controller method when the user clicks the confirm button.

CS Controller

```
[HttpPost] 
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Delete(string idFb, FormCollection from)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(urlAPISignature);
        var deleteTask = client.DeleteAsync("api/whitepages/" + idFb);
        deleteTask.Wait();
        var result = deleteTask.Result;
        if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

CSHTML File

```
    columns.Add().Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).Titled("").Filterable(false).RenderValueAs(model =>
           "<img title=\"supprimer\" class=\"delBtnWp\" data-idEpi=\"" + model.IdFb + "\" src=\"" + @Url.Content("~/Content/Images/trash-can.png") + "\" height=\"24\" width=\"24\" alt=\"del\" />");
.
.
.
.
<script>
        $(".delBtnWp").click(function () {
            var idFb = $(this).attr("data-IdFb");
            bootbox.dialog({
                title: 'Confirmer la suppression',
                message: 'Souhaitez-vous vraiment supprimer la ligne ?',
                buttons: {
                    danger: {
                        label: 'Non'
                    },
                    success: {
                        label: 'Oui',
                        className: "btn-success",
                        callback: function () {
                            success ();
                        }
                    }
                },
                callback: function (result) {
                    if (result) {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: "@Url.Action("Delete", "WhitePages")",
                            data: { IdFb: idFb },
                            success: function (data) {
                                alert("Yes");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

The compiler is not even reaching the controller action.

Comment: Have you enabled detailed error messages in the response and checked the stack trace of the 500 to determine the error cause? From the look of the code you've not included the anti-forgery token in the request, so that would be my first guess.

Comment: Also the attribute key is `data-idEpi`, not `data-idFb`

Comment: I don't see your sending a ForgeryToken via your AJAX call. Remove the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` from your ActionMethod in your Controller, or generate a forgery token on your View and then send it in your AJAX call.

Comment: I removed the *[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]*, and changed  *data-idEpi* to *data-idFb*, I no longer have 500 error.

Comment: But I send a null parameter to my controller action, so still not working

Comment: Controller name (idFb) and ajax name (IdFb) are not same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your case,  Remove the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` from your ActionMethod in your Controller, or generate a forgery token on your View and then send it in your AJAX call. Also you need to change `data-idEpi` to `data-idFb`. This would resolve your 500 Internal Server Error.